# JavaScript sorting array by nullable boolean, then string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I'm trying to sort an array of objects that has a nullable boolean value and a title. If an item in the list has been set as important the `"ReadUnderstood"` is either `true` or `false`, and if not, it's `null`. I want the list to be ordered alphabetically if `"ReadUnderstood"` is `true` or `null`, but if the value is `false`, I want it to the top of the list.

The closest to what I want I got with the code below. This returns the list in alphabetical order with the items where `"ReadUnderstood"` is `false` at the top of the list. But the items where `"ReadUnderstood"` is `true` ends up at the end of the list instead of in the alphabetiacal order. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
items = [
    {Title: 'A', ReadUnderstood: null},
    {Title: 'C', ReadUnderstood: false},
    {Title: 'E', ReadUnderstood: null},
    {Title: 'B', ReadUnderstood: true},
    {Title: 'D', ReadUnderstood: true},
    {Title: 'F', ReadUnderstood: null},
]

items.sort((a, b) => { 
    return (b.ReadUnderstood != null && b.ReadUnderstood == false) - (a.ReadUnderstood != null && a.ReadUnderstood == false) || a.Title - b.Title; 
})

Desired result:
items = [
    {Title: 'C', ReadUnderstood: false},
    {Title: 'A', ReadUnderstood: null},
    {Title: 'B', ReadUnderstood: true},
    {Title: 'D', ReadUnderstood: true},
    {Title: 'E', ReadUnderstood: null},
    {Title: 'F', ReadUnderstood: null},
]
```

Comment: Please add a sample of input and the expected output to create a [mcve]

Comment: What about multiple `false` values. Do they need to be sorted alphabetically as well?

Comment: That would be preferable as well, yes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. The [`compareFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) should return a number and based on whether it is positive, negative or zero, the two items `(a, b)` being compared are moved relative to each other. Subtracting booleans returns a number. So, the first condition works fine. For strings, you need to use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort them alphabetically.

Also, you can simplify the first condition. You don't need to check for `null` and make a strict equality check for `false`.

```
items.sort((a, b) => 
  (b.ReadUnderstood === false) - (a.ReadUnderstood === false) 
    || a.Title.localeCompare(b.Title)
)
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
const items = [
    {Title: 'A', ReadUnderstood: null},
    {Title: 'C', ReadUnderstood: false},
    {Title: 'E', ReadUnderstood: null},
    {Title: 'B', ReadUnderstood: true},
    {Title: 'D', ReadUnderstood: true},
    {Title: 'F', ReadUnderstood: null},
]

items.sort((a, b) => 
  (b.ReadUnderstood === false) - (a.ReadUnderstood === false) 
    || a.Title.localeCompare(b.Title)
)

console.log(items)
```

Comment: Weird. Your snippet is doing what I want, but when I tried to implement it in my code the list was only sorted alphabetically

Comment: @Hammis82 I'm using an implicit return in arrow functios. Since you have `{}` in your compareFunction, you need to add `return`

Comment: I didn't know a boolean could be subtracted/added to another boolean. Learning something every day. For others reading: `true` represents `1` and `false` represents `0`. `true - false //=> 1`

Comment: @adiga Yes, ofcourse :) I must have made a mistake when I copied it before, because it's working now. Thank you for your help :D

Comment: @3limin4t0r to expand on *"true represents 1"*: you can subtract anything in javascript. They are coerced to differenct types based on the operands. In [arithmetic context](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2),  [`ToNumber`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) is called on the 2 operands. From the linked table, you can see, *"The result is 1 if the argument is true. The result is +0 if the argument is false"*.

Comment: @3limin4t0r For objects, `ToNumber` calls, [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method. So if you override the `valueOf` function of objects, you can use them in arithmetic  operations. `var a = { valueOf: () => 1 }; var b = { valueOf: () => 2 }` So, `b - a` returns `1`

Comment: In TypeScript I just added + sign before each boolean comparision and it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can't subtract strings to compare them (subtracting non-number strings will always result in `NaN`).
You can only use `-` for sorting when the involved operands are numeric (numbers, booleans, etc...), otherwise you'll end up with a wrong sort order.

To compare strings you could either use `>` and `<`:

```
if(a.Text < b.Text)
  return -1;
else if(a.Text > b.Text)
  return 1;
else
  return 0;
```

Or use the [`String.prototype.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method:

```
return a.Text.localeCompare(b.Text);
```

`localeCompare()` also has the advantage of correctly sorting unicode characters (e.g. é).

Full working example with your items:

```js
let items = [
  {Title: 'A', ReadUnderstood: null},
  {Title: 'C', ReadUnderstood: false},
  {Title: 'E', ReadUnderstood: null},
  {Title: 'B', ReadUnderstood: true},
  {Title: 'D', ReadUnderstood: true},
  {Title: 'F', ReadUnderstood: null},
];


items.sort((a, b) => {
  let aReadUnderstood = a.ReadUnderstood !== false;
  let bReadUnderstood = b.ReadUnderstood !== false;
  if(aReadUnderstood !== bReadUnderstood)
    return aReadUnderstood - bReadUnderstood;
  else
    return a.Title.localeCompare(b.Title); 
});

console.log(items);
```

With a library like [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) you can get this a bit shorter and terser:

```js
let items = [
  {Title: 'A', ReadUnderstood: null},
  {Title: 'C', ReadUnderstood: false},
  {Title: 'E', ReadUnderstood: null},
  {Title: 'B', ReadUnderstood: true},
  {Title: 'D', ReadUnderstood: true},
  {Title: 'F', ReadUnderstood: null},
];

items = _.sortBy(items, e => [e.ReadUnderstood !== false, e.Title]);
console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
items.sort((a,b) => a.ReadUnderstood===false ? 
  -1 : (b.ReadUnderstood===false ? 1 : a.Title.localeCompare(b.Title)));
```

```js
items = [
    {Title: 'A', ReadUnderstood: null},
    {Title: 'C', ReadUnderstood: false},
    {Title: 'E', ReadUnderstood: null},
    {Title: 'B', ReadUnderstood: true},
    {Title: 'D', ReadUnderstood: true},
    {Title: 'F', ReadUnderstood: null},
]

items.sort((a,b) => a.ReadUnderstood===false ? 
      -1 : (b.ReadUnderstood===false ? 1 : a.Title.localeCompare(b.Title)));
      
console.log(items);
```

Comment: You need to compare the `ReadUnderstood` between the two objects otherwise the sort won't work correctly. When the `C` item is the first item in the array, your sort would sort it somewhere in the middle instead of at the top

Comment: Here's an example where it would fail: https://www.es6console.com/jze1oz4o/

Comment: Almost, you also need to handle the case where both are `false`, then they need to be sorted alphabetically. e.g. `C` should come before `G` in this example: https://www.es6console.com/jze23c0m/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option. First partitioning the array based on `item.ReadUnderstood === false`. Then sorting both arrays and concatenating them back together.

```js
Array.prototype.partition = function (callback, thisArg) {
  if (thisArg !== undefined) callback = callback.bind(thisArg);
  
  const partitions = { true: [], false: [] };
  this.forEach((item, ...args) => partitions[!!callback(item, ...args)].push(item));
  return [partitions[true], partitions[false]];
};

const items = [
  {Title: 'A', ReadUnderstood: null},
  {Title: 'C', ReadUnderstood: false},
  {Title: 'E', ReadUnderstood: null},
  {Title: 'B', ReadUnderstood: true},
  {Title: 'D', ReadUnderstood: true},
  {Title: 'F', ReadUnderstood: null},
];

const [ruFalse, ruOther] = items.partition(item => item.ReadUnderstood === false);
const byTitle = ({Title: t1}, {Title: t2}) => t1.localeCompare(t2);
console.log(ruFalse.sort(byTitle).concat(ruOther.sort(byTitle)));
```

If you don't care about `ruFalse` being sorted you can leave out `.sort(byTitle)` for that list.